# Example of funtion s.t. $y\longmapsto \int f(x,y)dx$ non measurable, but $f$ measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

1) Do you have an exemple of function s.t. $y\longmapsto \int f(x,y)dx$ is non measurable, but $f$ measurable ?

2) Do you have an exemple of a measurable function that is not integrable ?

I tried to find such function but with no success. If you have some other suggestion in my questions, it would be a pleasure :-)

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about the Lebesgue measure and if you know that $\int f (x,y)dx $ exists for all $y $, then the map in 1) is always measurable if $f $ is. This is essentially a consequence of the Fubuni Tonelli theorem.

For 2), take for example $f\equiv 1$ on $\Bbb {R } $. For a less trivial example, consider $f (x) = \frac {1}{x} \cdot 1_{(0,1)} $.

Comment: For 1) $y\longmapsto \int f(x,y)dx$ can exist for a.e. $y$ (and not for all $y$). Moreover, I don't see what Fubini-tonelli makes here since to apply this Theorem, you need $f\geq 0$, and it's not a hypothesis I imposed : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem

Comment: @MSE: Decompose $f $ into its positive and negative part and then add the two integrals together.

Comment: I think that if it would be that easy, every measurable function $f:X\times Y\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ would be integrable which is not the case, no ?

Comment: @MSE: You need to know a priori that the integral $\int f(x,y)\,dx$ exists for (almost) all $y$. Otherwise, the difference $\int f_+(x,y) \, dx - \int f_- (x,y) \, dx$ will be of the form $\infty - \infty$, which is bad.